# Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java

Tags: java, optimization, collections

I hope this question is not considered too basic for this forum, but we'll see. I'm wondering how to refactor some code for better performance that is getting run a bunch of times.

Say I'm creating a word frequency list, using a Map (probably a HashMap), where each key is a String with the word that's being counted and the value is an Integer that's incremented each time a token of the word is found.

In Perl, incrementing such a value would be trivially easy:

```
$map{$word}++;
```

But in Java, it's much more complicated. Here the way I'm currently doing it:

```
int count = map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) : 0;
map.put(word, count + 1);
```

Which of course relies on the autoboxing feature in the newer Java versions. I wonder if you can suggest a more efficient way of incrementing such a value. Are there even good performance reasons for eschewing the Collections framework and using a something else instead?

Update: I've done a test of several of the answers. See below.

Comment: I think it would be the same for java.util.Hashtable.

Comment: Of course if would be same, because Hashtable is infact a Map.

Comment: Java 8 : computeIfAbsent example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37439971/1216775

Comment: Take a look at `Map::computeIfAbsent` and friends.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

### Some test results

I've gotten a lot of good answers to this question--thanks folks--so I decided to run some tests and figure out which method is actually fastest. The five methods I tested are these:

- the "ContainsKey" method that I presented in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java)
- the "TestForNull" method suggested by Aleksandar Dimitrov
- the "AtomicLong" method suggested by Hank Gay
- the "Trove" method suggested by jrudolph
- the "MutableInt" method suggested by phax.myopenid.com

### Method

Here's what I did...

1. created five classes that were identical except for the differences shown below. Each class had to perform an operation typical of the scenario I presented: opening a 10MB file and reading it in, then performing a frequency count of all the word tokens in the file. Since this took an average of only 3 seconds, I had it perform the frequency count (not the I/O) 10 times.
2. timed the loop of 10 iterations but *not the I/O operation* and recorded the total time taken (in clock seconds) essentially using [Ian Darwin's method in the Java Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=t85jM-ZwTX0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=java+cookbook&sig=ACfU3U1lAe1vnbVUwdIcWeTpaxZi1xVUXQ#PPA734,M1).
3. performed all five tests in series, and then did this another three times.
4. averaged the four results for each method.

### Results

I'll present the results first and the code below for those who are interested.

The **ContainsKey** method was, as expected, the slowest, so I'll give the speed of each method in comparison to the speed of that method.

- **ContainsKey:** 30.654 seconds (baseline)
- **AtomicLong:** 29.780 seconds (1.03 times as fast)
- **TestForNull:** 28.804 seconds (1.06 times as fast)
- **Trove:** 26.313 seconds (1.16 times as fast)
- **MutableInt:** 25.747 seconds (1.19 times as fast)

### Conclusions

It would appear that only the MutableInt method and the Trove method are significantly faster, in that only they give a performance boost of more than 10%. However, if threading is an issue, AtomicLong might be more attractive than the others (I'm not really sure). I also ran TestForNull with `final` variables, but the difference was negligible.

Note that I haven't profiled memory usage in the different scenarios. I'd be happy to hear from anybody who has good insights into how the MutableInt and Trove methods would be likely to affect memory usage.

Personally, I find the MutableInt method the most attractive, since it doesn't require loading any third-party classes. So unless I discover problems with it, that's the way I'm most likely to go.

### The code

Here is the crucial code from each method.

#### ContainsKey

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
...
Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
...
int count = freq.containsKey(word) ? freq.get(word) : 0;
freq.put(word, count + 1);
```

#### TestForNull

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
...
Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
...
Integer count = freq.get(word);
if (count == null) {
    freq.put(word, 1);
}
else {
    freq.put(word, count + 1);
}
```

#### AtomicLong

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
...
final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();
...
map.putIfAbsent(word, new AtomicLong(0));
map.get(word).incrementAndGet();
```

#### Trove

```
import gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap;
...
TObjectIntHashMap<String> freq = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
...
freq.adjustOrPutValue(word, 1, 1);
```

#### MutableInt

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
...
class MutableInt {
  int value = 1; // note that we start at 1 since we're counting
  public void increment () { ++value;      }
  public int  get ()       { return value; }
}
...
Map<String, MutableInt> freq = new HashMap<String, MutableInt>();
...
MutableInt count = freq.get(word);
if (count == null) {
    freq.put(word, new MutableInt());
}
else {
    count.increment();
}
```

Comment: Great work, well done. A minor comment - the putIfAbsent() call in the AtomicLong code will instantiate a new AtomicLong(0) even if one is already in the map. If you tweak this to use if (map.get(key) == null) instead, you will probably get an improvement in those test results.

Comment: I did the same thing recently with an approach similar to MutableInt.  I'm glad to hear it was the optimal solution (I just assumed it was, without doing any tests).

Comment: I wanted to add that the increment function in Trove is really just a convenient function. You should look into the map.apply(procedure) methods in trove too. The basic problem is autoboxing and the double lookup required, where the apply method comes from a functional programming (e.g. lisp) design

Comment: Although the MutableInt increment method is very fast, it it not thread-safe in general since the ++ operator is not atomic.

Comment: In the Atomic Long case wouldn't it be more efficient to do it in one step ( so you have only 1 expensive get operation instead of 2 )  "map.putIfAbsent(word, new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet();"

Comment: @smartnut007 map.putIfAbsent returns the previous value, which will be null on the first access, throwing a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thats a minor. It should have been " temp = new AtomicLong(1); prev = map.putIfAbsent(word,temp); if( prev != null ) prev.incrementAndGet(); "

Comment: You are not comparing apples to apples here. None of the other options are thread-safe, so the Atomic version should use a normal `HashMap`, not a `ConcurrentHashMap`, for equal comparison. It should also be an `AtomicInteger`, not an `AtomicLong`, again for equal comparison. --- Also, an `int[1]` would be a simple built-in version of `MutableInt`, not requiring a new class.

Comment: @gregory did you consider Java 8's `freq.compute(word, (key, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1)`? Internally it does one less hashed lookup than `containsKey`, it would be interesting to see how it compares to others, because of the lambda.

Comment: You could also do `freq.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum)`

Comment: Could you please add the [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to the benchmark or supply the full source so that I can test?

Answer (score 531):

Now there is a shorter way with Java 8 using [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

```
myMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)
```

or

```
myMap.merge(key, 1L, Long::sum)
```

for longs respectively.

What it does:

- if *key* do not exists, put *1* as value
- otherwise *sum 1* to the value linked to *key*

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Comment: always love java 8. Is this atomic? or should I surround it with a synchronized?

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me but 
`map.merge(key, 1, (a, b) -> a + b); `
did

Comment: @Tiina Atomicity characteristics are implementation specific, cf. [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-): "The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties. In particular, all implementations of subinterface ConcurrentMap must document whether the function is applied once atomically only if the value is not present."

Comment: For groovy, it wouldn't accept `Integer::sum` as a BiFunction, and didn't like @russter answer the way it was written. This worked for me
`Map.merge(key, 1, { a, b -> a + b})`

Comment: @russter, I know your comment was over a year ago but do you happen to remember why it didn't work for you?  Did you get a compilation error or was the value not incremented?

Comment: @Tiina For concurrency, choose a `Map` implementation that implements [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). Two are bundled with Java: [`ConcurrentSkipList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: flawless answer

Comment: This method uses boxed Integers, meaning repeated summations will result in `N` object creations, rather than mutating the same `int` variable. There are better options in regards to performance.

Comment: @Hatefiend for the first 126 increments (per key!), there will be no object creation, as reusing the `Integer` instances is mandatory. For values beyond that, it’s runtime specific whether new objects are created. In contrast, using a mutable object always requires the creation of a distinct new object for each key. So, don’t make general statement about performance. The performance depends on the number of keys and average number of increments per key.

Answer (score 49):

A little research in 2016: https://github.com/leventov/java-word-count, [benchmark source code](https://github.com/leventov/java-word-count/blob/8a12a5ea4f53f01b9ee0e57f8aec70d75bc2030d/src/jmh/java/com/koloboke/wordcount/WordCount.java)

Best results per method (smaller is better):

```
                 time, ms
kolobokeCompile  18.8
koloboke         19.8
trove            20.8
fastutil         22.7
mutableInt       24.3
atomicInteger    25.3
eclipse          26.9
hashMap          28.0
hppc             33.6
hppcRt           36.5
```

Time\space results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. It would be cool to add Guava's Multiset (for example, HashMultiset) to the benchmark.

Answer (score 49):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String key = "a random key";
int count = map.getOrDefault(key, 0); // ensure count will be one of 0,1,2,3,...
map.put(key, count + 1);
```

And that's how you increment a value with simple code.

Benefit:

- No need to add a new class or use another concept of mutable int
- Not relying on any library
- Easy to understand what's going on exactly (Not too much abstraction)

Downside:

- The hash map will be searched twice for get() and put(). So it will not be the most performant code.

Theoretically, once you call get(), you already know where to put(), so you should not have to search again. But searching in hash map usually takes a very minimal time that you can kind of ignore this performance issue.

But if you are very serious about the issue, you are a perfectionist, another way is to use merge method, this is (probably) more efficient than the previous code snippet as you will be (theoretically) searching the map only once: (though this code is not obvious from first sight, it's short and performant)

```
map.merge(key, 1, (a,b) -> a+b);
```

Suggestion: you should care about code readability more than little performance gain in most of the time. If the first code snippet is easier for you to understand then use it. But if you are able to understand the 2nd one fine then you can also go for it!

Comment: The getOfDefault method is not available in JAVA 7. How can I achieve this in JAVA 7?

Comment: You may have to rely on other answers then. This only works in Java 8.

Comment: +1 for the merge solution, this will be the highest performing function because you only have to pay 1 time for the hashcode calculation (in the case the Map you are using it on properly supports the method), instead of potentially paying for it 3 times

Comment: Using method inference:   map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)

Answer (score 41):

As a follow-up to my own comment: Trove looks like the way to go. If, for whatever reason, you wanted to stick with the standard JDK, [ConcurrentMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) and [AtomicLong](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) can make the code a *tiny* bit nicer, though YMMV.

```
    final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();
    map.putIfAbsent("foo", new AtomicLong(0));
    map.get("foo").incrementAndGet();
```

will leave `1` as the value in the map for `foo`. Realistically, increased friendliness to threading is all that this approach has to recommend it.

Comment: The putIfAbsent() returns the value. It could be a big improvement to store the returned value in a local variable and use it to incrementAndGet() rather than call get again.

Comment: putIfAbsent can return a null value if the specified key is not already associated with a value inside Map so I would be careful to use the returned value.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-

Comment: @bumbur the solution should be obvious. Remember the new `AtomicLong` passed to `putIfAbsent` and the return value of the method, followed by using the right one for the increment. Of course, since Java 8 it’s even simpler to use `map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> new AtomicLong(0)) .incrementAndGet();`…

Answer (score 36):

### Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is your friend...

...at least in some cases. They have this nice [*AtomicLongMap*](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html). Especially nice because you are dealing with *long* as value in your map.

E.g.

```java
AtomicLongMap<String> map = AtomicLongMap.create();
[...]
map.getAndIncrement(word);
```

Also possible to add more then 1 to the value:

```java
map.getAndAdd(word, 112L);
```

Comment: `AtomicLongMap#getAndAdd` takes a primitive `long` and not the wrapper class; there's no point in doing `new Long()`. And `AtomicLongMap` is a parameterized type; you should have declared it as `AtomicLongMap<String>`.

Answer (score 30):

It's always a good idea to look at the [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) for this kind of thing. In this case a [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) will do the trick:

```
Multiset bag = Multisets.newHashMultiset();
String word = "foo";
bag.add(word);
bag.add(word);
System.out.println(bag.count(word)); // Prints 2
```

There are Map-like methods for iterating over keys/entries, etc. Internally the implementation currently uses a `HashMap<E, AtomicInteger>`, so you will not incur boxing costs.

Comment: The above answeer needs to reflect  tovares response. The api has changed  since its posting (3 years ago :))

Comment: Does the `count()` method on a multiset run in O(1) or O(n) time (worstcase)?  The docs are unclear on this point.

Comment: My algorithm for this kind of thing:

if ( hasApacheLib(thing) ) return apacheLib;
else if ( hasOnGuava(thing) ) return guava.

Usually I don't get past these two steps. :)

Answer (score 23):

You should be aware of the fact that your original attempt

```
int count = map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) : 0;
```

contains two potentially expensive operations on a map, namely `containsKey` and `get`. The former performs an operation potentially pretty similar to the latter, so you're doing the same work *twice*!

If you look at the API for Map, `get` operations usually return `null` when the map does not contain the requested element.

Note that this will make a solution like

```
map.put( key, map.get(key) + 1 );
```

dangerous, since it might yield `NullPointerException`s. You should check for a `null` first.

**Also note**, and this is very important, that `HashMap`s *can* contain `nulls` by definition. So not every returned `null` says "there is no such element". In this respect, `containsKey` behaves *differently* from `get` in actually telling you *whether* there is such an element. Refer to the API for details.

For your case, however, you might not want to distinguish between a stored `null` and "noSuchElement". If you don't want to permit `null`s you might prefer a `Hashtable`. Using a wrapper library as was already proposed in other answers might be a better solution to manual treatment, depending on the complexity of your application.

To complete the answer (and I forgot to put that in at first, thanks to the edit function!), the best way of doing it natively, is to `get` into a `final` variable, check for `null` and `put` it back in with a `1`. The variable should be `final` because it's immutable anyway. The compiler might not need this hint, but its clearer that way.

```
final HashMap map = generateRandomHashMap();
final Object key = fetchSomeKey();
final Integer i = map.get(key);
if (i != null) {
    map.put(i + 1);
} else {
    // do something
}
```

If you do not want to rely on autoboxing, you should say something like `map.put(new Integer(1 + i.getValue()));` instead.

Comment: To avoid the problem of initial unmapped/null values in groovy I end up doing: 

counts.put(key, (counts.get(key) ?: 0) + 1)
// overly complex version of ++

Comment: Or, most simply:  counts = [:].withDefault{0}  // ++ away

Answer (score 20):

Another way would be creating a mutable integer:

```
class MutableInt {
  int value = 0;
  public void inc () { ++value; }
  public int get () { return value; }
}
...
Map<String,MutableInt> map = new HashMap<String,MutableInt> ();
MutableInt value = map.get (key);
if (value == null) {
  value = new MutableInt ();
  map.put (key, value);
} else {
  value.inc ();
}
```

of course this implies creating an additional object but the overhead in comparison to creating an Integer (even with Integer.valueOf) should not be so much.

Comment: You don't want to start the MutableInt off at 1 the first time you put it in the map?

Comment: Apache's commons-lang has a MutableInt already written for you.

Comment: Making `inc` `final` could theoretically provide a measurable benefit here.

Answer (score 13):

You can make use of [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method in `Map` interface provided in **Java 8**.

```
final Map<String,AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("A", k->new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet();
map.computeIfAbsent("B", k->new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet();
map.computeIfAbsent("A", k->new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet(); //[A=2, B=1]
```

The method `computeIfAbsent` checks if the specified key is already associated with a value or not? If no associated value then it attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function. In any case it returns the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null.

On a side note if you have a situation where multiple threads update a common sum you can have a look at [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) class.Under high contention, expected throughput of this class is significantly higher than `AtomicLong`, at the expense of higher space consumption.

Comment: why concurrentHashmap and AtomicLong?

Answer (score 10):

Quite simple, just use the built-in function in `Map.java` as followed

```java
map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
```

Comment: This does not increment the value, it just sets the current value or 0 if no value was assigned to the key.

Comment: You can increment  the value by `++`... OMG, it's so simple. @siegi

Comment: For the record: `++` does not work anywhere in this expression because a variable is needed as its operand but there are just values. Your addition of `+ 1` works though. Now your solution is the same as in [off99555s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33711386/1347968).

Answer (score 8):

Memory rotation may be an issue here, since every boxing of an int larger than or equal to 128 causes an object allocation (see Integer.valueOf(int)). Although the garbage collector very efficiently deals with short-lived objects, performance will suffer to some degree.

If you know that the number of increments made will largely outnumber the number of keys (=words in this case), consider using an int holder instead. Phax already presented code for this. Here it is again, with two changes (holder class made static and initial value set to 1):

```
static class MutableInt {
  int value = 1;
  void inc() { ++value; }
  int get() { return value; }
}
...
Map<String,MutableInt> map = new HashMap<String,MutableInt>();
MutableInt value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
  value = new MutableInt();
  map.put(key, value);
} else {
  value.inc();
}
```

If you need extreme performance, look for a Map implementation which is directly tailored towards primitive value types. jrudolph mentioned [GNU Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net).

By the way, a good search term for this subject is "histogram".

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use Java 8 Map::compute().
It considers the case when a key doesn't exist, too.

```
Map.compute(num, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Comment: `mymap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling containsKey() it is faster just to call map.get and check if the returned value is null or not.

```
    Integer count = map.get(word);
    if(count == null){
        count = 0;
    }
    map.put(word, count + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Use a Bag alorithm like the sets contained in Google Collections.
2. Create mutable container which you can use in the Map:

```
    class My{
        String word;
        int count;
    }
```

And use put("word", new My("Word") ); Then you can check if it exists and increment when adding.

Avoid rolling your own solution using lists, because if you get innerloop searching and sorting, your performance will stink. The first HashMap solution is actually quite fast, but a proper like that found in Google Collections is probably better.

Counting words using Google Collections, looks something like this:

```
    HashMultiset s = new HashMultiset();
    s.add("word");
    s.add("word");
    System.out.println(""+s.count("word") );
```

Using the HashMultiset is quite elegent, because a bag-algorithm is just what you need when counting words.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that this is a bottleneck? Have you done any performance analysis?

Try using the NetBeans profiler (its free and built into NB 6.1) to look at hotspots.

Finally, a JVM upgrade (say from 1.5->1.6) is often a cheap performance booster. Even an upgrade in build number can provide good performance boosts. If you are running on Windows and this is a server class application, use -server on the command line to use the Server Hotspot JVM. On Linux and Solaris machines this is autodetected.

Answer (score 3):

Google Collections HashMultiset :
 - quite elegant to use
 - but consume CPU and memory

Best would be to have a method like : `Entry<K,V> getOrPut(K);` 
(elegant, and low cost)

Such a method will compute hash and index only once,
and then we could do what we want with the entry
(either replace or update the value).

More elegant:
 - take a `HashSet<Entry>`
 - extend it so that `get(K)` put a new Entry if needed
 - Entry could be your own object.
--> `(new MyHashSet()).get(k).increment();`

Answer (score 3):

A variation on the MutableInt approach that might be even faster, if a bit of a hack, is to use a single-element int array:

```
Map<String,int[]> map = new HashMap<String,int[]>();
...
int[] value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) 
  map.put(key, new int[]{1} );
else
  ++value[0];
```

It would be interesting if you could rerun your performance tests with this variation.  It might be the fastest.

---

Edit: The above pattern worked fine for me, but eventually I changed to use Trove's collections to reduce memory size in some very large maps I was creating -- and as a bonus it was also faster.

One really nice feature is that the `TObjectIntHashMap` class has a single `adjustOrPutValue` call that, depending on whether there is already a value at that key, will either put an initial value or increment the existing value.  This is perfect for incrementing:

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> map = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
...
map.adjustOrPutValue(key, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

"put" need "get" (to ensure no duplicate key).
So directly do a "put",
and if there was a previous value, then do an addition:

```
Map map = new HashMap ();

MutableInt newValue = new MutableInt (1); // default = inc
MutableInt oldValue = map.put (key, newValue);
if (oldValue != null) {
  newValue.add(oldValue); // old + inc
}
```

If count starts at 0, then add 1: (or any others values...)

```
Map map = new HashMap ();

MutableInt newValue = new MutableInt (0); // default
MutableInt oldValue = map.put (key, newValue);
if (oldValue != null) {
  newValue.setValue(oldValue + 1); // old + inc
}
```

*Notice :* This code is not thread safe. Use it to build then use the map, not to concurrently update it.

*Optimization :* In a loop, keep old value to become the new value of next loop.

```
Map map = new HashMap ();
final int defaut = 0;
final int inc = 1;

MutableInt oldValue = new MutableInt (default);
while(true) {
  MutableInt newValue = oldValue;

  oldValue = map.put (key, newValue); // insert or...
  if (oldValue != null) {
    newValue.setValue(oldValue + inc); // ...update

    oldValue.setValue(default); // reuse
  } else
    oldValue = new MutableInt (default); // renew
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The various primitive wrappers, e.g., `Integer` are immutable so there's really not a more concise way to do what you're asking *unless* you can do it with something like [AtomicLong](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html). I can give that a go in a minute and update. BTW, [Hashtable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) *is* a part of the [Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Apache Collections Lazy Map (to initialize values to 0) and use MutableIntegers from Apache Lang as values in that map.

Biggest cost is having to serach the map twice in your method. In mine you have to do it just once. Just get the value (it will get initialized if absent) and increment it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Functional Java](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava) library's `TreeMap` datastructure has an `update` method in the latest trunk head:

```
public TreeMap<K, V> update(final K k, final F<V, V> f)
```

Example usage:

```
import static fj.data.TreeMap.empty;
import static fj.function.Integers.add;
import static fj.pre.Ord.stringOrd;
import fj.data.TreeMap;

public class TreeMap_Update
  {public static void main(String[] a)
    {TreeMap<String, Integer> map = empty(stringOrd);
     map = map.set("foo", 1);
     map = map.update("foo", add.f(1));
     System.out.println(map.get("foo").some());}}
```

This program prints "2".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use a `HashBag`. It will be the most efficient approach in terms of memory usage and it will also perform well in terms of execution speed.

`HashBag` is backed by a `MutableObjectIntMap` which stores primitive ints instead of `Counter` objects. This reduces memory overhead and improves execution speed.

`HashBag` provides the API you'd need since it's a `Collection` that also allows you to query for the number of occurrences of an item.

Here's an example from the [Eclipse Collections Kata](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections-kata).

```
MutableBag<String> bag =
  HashBag.newBagWith("one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three");

Assert.assertEquals(3, bag.occurrencesOf("three"));

bag.add("one");
Assert.assertEquals(2, bag.occurrencesOf("one"));

bag.addOccurrences("one", 4);
Assert.assertEquals(6, bag.occurrencesOf("one"));
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how efficient it is but the below code works as well.You need to define a `BiFunction` at the beginning. Plus, you can make more than just increment with this method.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> strInt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> bi = (x,y) -> {
        if(x == null)
            return y;
        return x+y;
    };
    strInt.put("abc", 0);


    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abcd", 1, bi);

    System.out.println(strInt.get("abc"));
    System.out.println(strInt.get("abcd"));
}
```

output is

```
3
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting using streams and `getOrDefault`:

```
String s = "abcdeff";
s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
 .forEach(c -> {
     int count = countMap.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1;
     countMap.put(c, count);
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

Since a lot of people search Java topics for Groovy answers, here's how you can do it in Groovy:

```
dev map = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
map.put("key1", 3)

map.merge("key1", 1) {a, b -> a + b}
map.merge("key2", 1) {a, b -> a + b}
```

Answer (score -3):

Hope I'm understanding your question correctly, I'm coming to Java from Python so I can empathize with your struggle.

if you have

```
map.put(key, 1)
```

you would do

```
map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

The simple and easy way in java 8 is the following:

```
final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();
    map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet();
```