# Problem counting in Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194215/problem-in-count-field-in-arraylist-and-save-it) about counting the number of times a word is in ArrayList:

```
ACU ACU ACU ACU ACY ACY AER AER AER AGC
```

So for
ACU we will get 4,
ACY we will get 2,
AER we will get 3,
AGC we will get 1.

I got some help but I cannot make it work.
Darren gave me a very important answer:

```
Map<String, Integer>wordCount = new HashMap<String, int>();
  for(String seq : yourWordList){
     wordCount.put(seq, wordCount.get(seq++));
  }
```

But in the part `wordCount.put(seq, wordCount.get(seq++));`
I get an error that cannot convert from String to int, I tried to modify the code to work
but I'm getting incorrect numbers

ACU  0
ACU  1
ACU  1
ACU  1
ACY  1
ACY  2
AER  2
AER  3
AER  3

```
int value=0;
Map<String, Integer>wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String seq : WordList){
  Set<String> set = wordCount.keySet();
  value = set.size();
  wordCount.put(seq, value));
}
```

Please help me on this one. Thanks to all.

Comment: @Edgar - Whether or not this is "homework", you are not going to learn if you simply cut-and-paste code provided in SO answers.  You should try to code and debug your own stuff.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I tried to debug my self, the problem here was that I am not familiar using maps and hash, sorry if this seems to be copy paste, but i really tried to run that, even I modified that code my own, thats why I ask for your expert comments. Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
Map<String, Integer>wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String seq : yourWordList) {
  Integer count = wordCount.get(seq);
  wordCount.put(seq, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
}
```

The `Map` is from `String` to `Integer`. `Integer` is immutable so you can't increment it in place. You have to retrieve the current value, increment it and put it back. You're trying to call `wordCount.get(seq++)`, which doesn't make a lot of sense. `get()` has to be passed in a `String` (for this kind of `Map`) and you can't use `++` on an immutable `Integer` anyway.

Comment: Cletus you saved my day

the result is accurate

ACU value: 4
ACY Value: 2
AER Value: 3...

Which is correct, Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

`wordCount.get(seq++)` is probably the issue--try incrementing the return value of the get method (right now you're apparently attempting to increment the String argument, triggering the error. Try changing that to `wordCount.get(seq)+1`

Comment: Your answer is right, but it's probably best not to give a direct answer to a "homework" problem.

Comment: I agree with Justin.
The second code snippet seems to be completely off-mark. Fix the first code snippet with Justin's suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I still got the issue

java.lang.NullPointerException

even if I try wordCount.get(seq)+1
I guess the problem is that it doesn´t increment :(

Comment: The NullPointerException was likely caused by the fact that each word `seq` had never been initialized to zero in the map. Therefore, each of those items would have evaluated to `null+1` at runtime. (Merely an FYI, as you have your cut-and-paste homework answer provided above at this point.)

Comment: thanks for your comments, as I said, I didnt mean this to be cut and paste, I really tried to run the code and modify it myself.

Thanks for your time, Greetings,

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution that uses [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
Multiset<String> words = HashMultiset.create();
for (String word : wordList)
    words.add(word);

for (String word : words.elementSet())
    System.out.println(word + ": " + words.count(word));
```

Comment: @flup Thanks for your kind comment, and for bumping up the post so I know to update it to current. :-)