# Atomically incrementing counters stored in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava, concurrenthashmap

I would like to collect some metrics from various places in a web app. To keep it simple, all these will be counters and therefore the only modifier operation is to increment them by 1.

The increments will be concurrent and often. The reads (dumping the stats) is a rare operation.

I was thinking to use a *ConcurrentHashMap*. The issue is how to *increment* the counters correctly. Since the map doesn't have an "increment" operation, I need to read the current value first, increment it than put the new value in the map. Without more code, this is not an atomic operation.

Is it possible to achieve this without synchronization (which would defeat the purpose of the *ConcurrentHashMap*)? Do I need to look at [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) ?

Thanks for any pointers.

---

**P.S.**
There is a related question on SO ([Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java)) but focused on performance and not multi-threading

**UPDATE**
For those arriving here through searches on the same topic: besides the answers below, there's a useful [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sjlee0/robust-and-scalable-concurrent-programming-lesson-from-the-trenches) which incidentally covers the same topic. See slides 24-33.

Answer (score 37):

In Java 8:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, LongAdder> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
```

Comment: in short form with link on method: `LongAdder::increment`

Comment: I meant java 8 method on link: `AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0); atomicInt::incrementAndGet`

Comment: You can use "more functional" approach in the code above

Comment: @pacman Can you provide exact code? I don't think my answer can be more functional.

Comment: `Map<String, LongAdder> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Consumer<LongAdder> function = LongAdder::increment;
function.accept(map.get("key"));`

Comment: I implied that `Consumer` is a reference on the method that invokes incrementing, it's a controversial question is link on function a part of FP

Comment: +1 This solution is suggested in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html

Answer (score 22):

Guava's new [AtomicLongMap](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.java) (in release 11) might address this need.

Comment: This is a perfect answer! Compare probability of concurrency mistake between Guava vs listed here custom code samples.

Answer (score 9):

You're pretty close.  Why don't you try something like a `ConcurrentHashMap<Key, AtomicLong>`?
If your `Key`s (metrics) are unchanging, you could even just use a standard `HashMap` (they are threadsafe if readonly, but you'd be well advised to make this explicit with an `ImmutableMap` from Google Collections or `Collections.unmodifiableMap`, etc.).

This way, you can use `map.get(myKey).incrementAndGet()` to bump statistics.

Comment: Just don't forget to store the `HashMap` in a `final` member. And better wrap the map in a `unmodifiable` wrapper. Better yet, you can use `ImmutableMap` from Guava (superset of google collection) and it should be really really fast.

Comment: @Zwei: good point, edited the answer to include that advice :)

Comment: The list of metrics is built as they supply data (i.e. the map's keys will be added as the system runs and various collection points are hit; building the list a priori would be error-prone). I forgot about AtomicLong's incrementAndGet(), it's just what I need. If it didn't exist, I was thinking that another approach would have been for the metrics collectors not to increase the counters, but simply to add the request to do so in a queue maintained by the singleton. Thus, the callers only add() to a list, which periodically is read and processed. Not as simple, though.

Answer (score 7):

Other than going with `AtomicLong`, you can do the usual cas-loop thing:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Key,Long> counts =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<Key,Long>();

public void increment(Key key) {
    if (counts.putIfAbsent(key, 1)) == null) {
        return;
    }

    Long old;
    do {
       old = counts.get(key);
    } while (!counts.replace(key, old, old+1)); // Assumes no removal.
}
```

(I've not written a `do`-`while` loop for ages.)

For small values the `Long` will probably be "cached". For longer values, it may require allocation. But the allocations are actually extremely fast (and you can cache further) - depends upon what you expect, in the worst case.

Comment: I think that's right. Apologies to anyone looking at the previous broken code. (You could rearrange it so that it starts off with a `get`, a compare to null and only then try `putIfAbsent`, continuing with a normal `while` loop.)

Answer (score 1):

Got a necessity to do the same.
I'm using ConcurrentHashMap + AtomicInteger.
Also, ReentrantRW Lock was introduced for atomic flush(very similar behavior).

Tested with 10 Keys and 10 Threads per each Key. Nothing was lost. 
I just haven't tried several flushing threads yet, but hope it will work.

Massive singleusermode flush is torturing me...
I want to remove RWLock and break down flushing into small pieces. Tomorrow.

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String,AtomicInteger> counters = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
private ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void count(String invoker) {

    rwLock.readLock().lock();

    try{
        AtomicInteger currentValue = counters.get(invoker);
        // if entry is absent - initialize it. If other thread has added value before - we will yield and not replace existing value
        if(currentValue == null){
            // value we want to init with
            AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger(0);
            // try to put and get old
            AtomicInteger oldValue = counters.putIfAbsent(invoker, newValue);
            // if old value not null - our insertion failed, lets use old value as it's in the map
            // if old value is null - our value was inserted - lets use it
            currentValue = oldValue != null ? oldValue : newValue;
        }

        // counter +1
        currentValue.incrementAndGet();
    }finally {
        rwLock.readLock().unlock();
    }

}

/**
 * @return Map with counting results
 */
public Map<String, Integer> getCount() {
    // stop all updates (readlocks)
    rwLock.writeLock().lock();
    try{
        HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // read all Integers to a new map
        for(Map.Entry<String,AtomicInteger> entry: counters.entrySet()){
            resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().intValue());
        }
        // reset ConcurrentMap
        counters.clear();
        return resultMap;

    }finally {
        rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }

}
```

Comment: For every time getCount is called its going to prevent the writes. This will guarantee value consistency.But will impacts performance.

Answer (score 1):

I did a benchmark to compare the performance of `LongAdder` and `AtomicLong`.

`LongAdder` had a better performance in my benchmark: for 500 iterations using a map with size 100 (10 concurrent threads), the average time for LongAdder was 1270ms while that for AtomicLong was 1315ms.