# Java: How to keep a relation between three objects

Tags: java, collections, tuples

I'm looking to store a list of relations between three objects, where two of the related objects will each only exist in one relation in the list and the third is a count that I can increment.  It's not very generalizable to SO at large, but you can see what I'm doing here

```
    public class Transaction implements AutoCloseable {
    private final Connection conn;
    private final Map<String, Map.Entry<PreparedStatement, Integer>> sts = new HashMap<>();

    Transaction(final Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    <T> void batch(final String st, final List<T> ts,
            final BatchingInstructions<T> bi) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement stat;
        int counter;

        // if statement has already been created, retrieve statement and batch count
        if (sts.containsKey(st)) {
            final Map.Entry<PreparedStatement, Integer> m = sts.get(st);
            stat = m.getKey();
            counter = m.getValue();
        } else {
            // else create statement and batch count
            stat = conn.prepareStatement(getInsert(st));
            counter = 0;
            sts.put(st, // Can't do a new Map.Entry, really
        }

        for (final T t : ts) {
            bi.batch(stat, t);
            stat.addBatch();
            // increment how many times a batch has been added to the statement.
            // execute batch if necessary.
            if (++counter > 5000) {
                stat.executeBatch();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        for (final Map.Entry<PreparedStatement, Integer> m : sts.values()) {
            if (m.getValue() > 0) {
                m.getKey().executeBatch();
            }
            m.getKey().close();
        }
        conn.commit();
    }
```

Guava's Table doesn't exactly work, and a `Map<String, Map<Statement, Integer>>` is also not ideal, and it's all complicated by the need to increment one of the values (though for that I'll probably use the mutableInt solution found here [Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java)).

I was wondering if anybody knew of any straightforward solutions to this issue, possibly in third party libraries?

---

Using the accepted answer, I was able to have the new class do a number of other useful things.

```
class BatchPreparedStatement implements AutoCloseable {
    private final PreparedStatement st;
    private int counter = 0;

    BatchPreparedStatement(final PreparedStatement st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    <T> void addBatch(final BatchingInstructions<T> bi, final T t)
            throws SQLException {
        bi.batch(st, t);
        st.addBatch();
        executeBatch(10000);
    }

    void executeBatch(final int count) throws SQLException {
        if (counter++ > count) {
            st.executeBatch();
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    void finished() throws SQLException {
        executeBatch(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        st.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you you create a Class that holds the Statement, the count and handles all the addBatching plus other miscellaneous activities.

```
class BatchPreparedStatementHolder {

    private int batchCount;
    private PreparedStatement ps;

    public BatchPreparedStatementHolder(PreparedStatement statement){
        batchCount = 0;
        ps = statment;
    }

    public void addBatch(){
        ps.addBatch();
        // increment how many times a batch has been added to the statement.
        // execute batch if necessary.
        if (++batchCount> 5000) {
            ps.executeBatch();
            batchCount = 0;
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class suggestion is pretty good but a little heavy weight if you just need something simple. I would use something like a **HashMap**. (other languages call these "dictionaries"). I don't have time to read all your code, but it looks like you may be using Maps?

Anyways, you could make the key the auto-incremented value (as in databases) and the value could be, say a tuple or array of the other two values. See the following link for good advice on HashMaps:

http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/02/10-examples-of-hashmap-in-java-programming-tutorial.html

Or perhaps just make an array where the index refers to the auto-incremented function, and the content is another array?

Not sure exactly what you need but these might work!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keeping the Map.Entry in the map you can keep the nested class .. which will be easy to handle.. something like that ..

```
class Transaction implements AutoCloseable {
            private final Connection conn;

            class MapValue {
                PreparedStatement p;
                int index ;
                public MapValue(){}
                public MapValue(PreparedStatement p , int i)
                {
                    index= i;
                    this.p=p;
                }
            }
            private final Map<String, MapValue> sts = new HashMap<>();

            Transaction(final Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                this.conn = conn;
            }

            <T> void batch(final String st, final List<T> ts,
                    final BatchingInstructions<T> bi) throws SQLException {
                final PreparedStatement stat;
                int counter;

                // if statement has already been created, retrieve statement and batch count
                if (sts.containsKey(st)) {
                     MapValue  m = sts.get(st);
                    stat = m.p;
                    counter = m.index;
                } else {
                    // else create statement and batch count

                    stat = conn.prepareStatement(getInsert(st));
                    MapValue m = new MapValue(stat, 0);
                    sts.put(st, m);

                }

                for (final T t : ts) {
                    bi.batch(stat, t);
                    stat.addBatch();
                    // increment how many times a batch has been added to the statement.
                    // execute batch if necessary.
                    if (++counter > 5000) {
                        stat.executeBatch();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void close() throws Exception {
                    for (final Map.Entry<PreparedStatement, Integer> m : sts.values()) {
                        if (m.getValue() > 0) {
                            m.getKey().executeBatch();
                        }
                        m.getKey().close();
                    }
                    conn.commit();
                }


      }
```