# Java: Count fast a number of items shared among multiple sets

Tags: java, set

I have 10 sets on the input, where each set contains hundreds of items (strings).

**What i want:**

I want to find items that are shared by at least two sets and sort them by number of occurrences across different sets in descending order.

**My approach:**

I've created the following code. However, I want to know, if exists a more efficient way to do this...

```
Map<String, Integer> sharedCounts = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Set<String> words = getWords(i);
  for (String word : words) {
    if (sharedCounts.containsKey(word)) {
      sharedCounts.put(word, commons.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
      sharedCounts.put(word, 1);
    }
  }
}

Map<String, Integer> sorted = sharedCounts.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: It looks ok. Map's `put` and `containsKey` have `O(1)` time complexity and otherwise you iterate over all sets over all words exactly once, giving `O(n)` where `n` is a total number of words in all sets. The slowest part is actually sorting, as this would be `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: By the way, I have just realised something - how is your `sharedCounts` map different from `sorted` map? They are both hash maps which means unordered. The whole sorting is redundant. Don't you want to collect to list? Or maybe to tree map, but making count a key and word a value?

Comment: Yep, you have to generate a tree map. I just tried, and it sorts alphabetically, no matter which word has greater count of occurences.

Comment: why do you sort before putting in a map?

Comment: What is the difference between the variables `sharedCounts` and `commons`?  Are those supposed to be the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm for computing the count has asymptotic complexity of O(SUM(N<sub>*i*</sub>)), where N<sub>*i*</sub> is the size of *i*-th set of words. This is as fast as it gets.

It appears that you are missing a filtering step, where you discard words with the count of one.

```
Map<String, Integer> sorted = commons.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1) // <<== Add this line
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Overall complexity is O(SUM(N<sub>*i*</sub>)+N<sub>distinct-dup</sub>*log(N<sub>distinct-dup</sub>)), where N<sub>distinct-dup</sub> is the number of distinct words that have duplicates.

Comment: That's a nice practical improvement, however theoretical time complexity still stays as `O(nlogn)`. I am not sure whether we can make it any better than this.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I added filtering to make the algorithm return what OP wants (i.e. items that are shared by at least two sets), not to improve the running time, which is, of course, O(N*logN) worst case.

Comment: If the order is `O(SUM(Ni)+Ndistinct-dup*log(Ndistinct-dup))`  then we still don't know which part is slower, `O(SUM(Ni))` or `O(Ndistinct-dup*log(Ndistinct-dup))`.   If `Sum(Ni)` is large and `Ndistinct` is small, then it would be useful to work on speeding up the counting section.  There are ways to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of iterating over all elements in each `Set` you can simply combine all sets using `oneSet.addAll(anotherSet)` and then fill your `sharedCounts` map

```
Set<String> combinedSet = new HashSet<String>(); 

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Set<String> words = getWords(i);
  combinedSet.addAll(words);
}

Map<String, Integer> sharedCounts = new HashMap<>();

for (String word : combinedSet) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     Set<String> words = getWords(i);
     if (words.contains(word)) {
        if (sharedCounts.containsKey(word)) {
           sharedCounts.put(word, commons.get(word) + 1);
        } else {
           sharedCounts.put(word, 1);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: And how are you going to create `sharedCounts` map having a single set with all words without duplicates?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak look up, I ment something like that

Comment: So now think what is a time complexity of hash set's `contains` and how many times you do this. The code you proposed is not any shorter or more readable than OP's code, and also has far worse performance.