# Perl hash increment how does this work?

Tags: perl

I have the following in the perl code:

```
$art_entities->{$rel_art_path}++;
```

I see that it is a post increment on a hash, how does it work? What would be something similar in Java or C#?

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand? Are you looking for internals of Perl and how it implements hashes?

Comment: No, just what does the code means, and what's the equivalent in languages such as java or c#

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/81346/734304

Answer (score 4):

The `++` operator returns the value and then increments the variable by one. Hashes are just unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated string key; incrementing a scalar in a hash is no different from incrementing a scalar outside of a hash.

The following are functionally equivalent:

```
$hash{foo}++;
$hash_ref->{foo}++;
$foo++;
```

There's a little extra magic built in to [Perl's auto-increment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement), though:

> If you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been
>   used in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however,
>   the variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set,
>   and has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern
>   `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`, the increment is done as a string, preserving
>   each character within its range, with carry:
>
> ```
> print ++($foo = "99");    # prints "100"
> print ++($foo = "a0");    # prints "a1"
> print ++($foo = "Az");    # prints "Ba"
> print ++($foo = "zz");    # prints "aaa"
> ```
>
> `undef` is always treated as numeric, and in particular is changed to `0` before incrementing (so
>   that a post-increment of an undef value will return `0` rather than
>   `undef`).

Java and C# both have increment operators, but as far as I know, they're not nearly as magical as Perl's. Java's `HashMap` provides `get()` and `put()` methods, so you don't get direct access to the underlying data:

```
map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
```

C# collections use square brackets, so if you had a `Dictionary`, for example:

```
dict["foo"]++;
```

Comment: According to the docs, both `map.get(key) + 1` and `dict["foo"]` will fail if the element doesn't already exists, which is almost always the case when `++` is used.

Answer (score 4):

It creates an element in the hash if it doesn't exist, then increments its value by one<sup>[1]</sup>.

For example,

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for split(//, 'abracadabra');
```

produces

```
my %counts = (
   a => 5,
   b => 2,
   c => 1,
   d => 1,
   r => 2,
);
```

It's also useful for filtering out duplicates. For example,

```
my %seen;
my @uniq = grep !$seen{$_}++, split(//, 'abracadabra');
```

produces

```
my @uniq = qw( a b r c d );
```

---

Perl:

```
my %dict;

++$dict{$key};   # $dict{$key}++ in scalar context gets optimized into ++$dict{$key}.
```

C#:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

int i;
dict.TryGetValue(key, out i);
dict[key] = i+1;
```

C#:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
   ++dict[key];
else
   dict[key] = 1;
```

Java:

```
Map<String, Integer> dict = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Integer i = dict.get(key);
if (i == null) {
   map.put(key, 1);
} else {
   map.put(key, i+1);
}
```

---

1. `++` has some "magical" behaviour if the variable being incremented contains a string (incrementing `a` into `b`, for example), but I don't think that's relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

```
$art_entities->{$rel_art_path}++;
```

`$art_entities` is a variable (a scalar, see the leading `$` sign). With the arrow syntax, it looks like it is an object.

`$rel_art_path` is another scalar variable.

`->{...}` accesses a field (right side of the arrow, in {curly braces}) from the object on the left side of the arrow.  Perl does not do much in terms of access limitations, i.e., there is no `public`, `private`, or `protected`. You could add your own code to enforce `private` access (see Perl Best Practices) or use a class framework like [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose).

The code uses the value of `$rel_art_path` as a field name in the `$art_entities` object.

In Java, this would be done with reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeOtherClass soc = new SomeOtherClass();
        doSomething(soc, "someValue");
        soc.print();
    }

    public static void doSomething(Object art_entities, String rel_art_path)
    throws Exception {
        Class<?> c = art_entities.getClass();
        Field field = c.getDeclaredField(rel_art_path);
        field.setInt(art_entities, field.getInt(art_entities) + 1);
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public int someValue = 0;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("my value is " + someValue);
    }
}
```

(I've used your variable names in the Java code to make it clearer which corresponds to which. Obviously they are Perl style (using underscores), not Java (camel case).)

In Java, this is hackish and quite a lot to write, in Perl it's short and normal.

Comment: `$art_entities` is a hash reference. It *could* be an object, but there's nothing in the OP's code to suggest that. I imagine the closest equivalent in Java would be fetching a value from a hashmap or the equivalent data structure, incrementing it, and storing the result.

Comment: $art_entities is a result from     $self->{_art_entities}, does that clarify things?

Comment: @HarveyLin There you have the same thing: `$self` is what Perl programmers often use for `this` in Java, even though it's not a keyword in Perl. `$self->{_art_entities}` refers to the member variable `_art_entities` of whatever object `$self` is. `_art_entities` does not start with a `$`, so there is no indirection, and you'd have this as normal member access in Java (e.g., "soc.someValue" in my example code), without need for reflection.

Comment: And this is how art_entities gets passed to $self: my %art_entities;
   $self->{_art_entities} = \%art_entities;