# Increment of value in Hashmap<Object,Integer>, Error "Integer cannot be converted to P(object)" Java

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, increment

I'm trying to increment of value in hashmap. I'm using Java 8 and Netbeans, so wrote this code:

```
Map<P, Integer>color_match_hash = new HashMap<P, Integer>();
for(int k=0; k<color_match_hash.size(); k++){
if(color_match_hash.get(k).equals(P_Color.get(i))){
    color_match_hash.merge(color_match_hash.get(k), 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

}

P is an object with 5 Integers.
It is a simple algorithm, in which I want to increment value of key (k)
and I got "incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to P".
What I'm doing wrong?
I must add that I tried a lot of ways to increment this and in every I had the same message. [Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have created a `HashMap` with key of type `P` and value of type `Integer`.

First of all, you are iterating the map like we do for a list or array.

Secondly, this is a wrong usage - `color_match_hash.get(k)`. The `get` method expects a value having a data type `P` (the key).

You can read [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map), to see different ways to iterate over a map.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very useful suggestion. Bad iteration was the problem