# How to increment value of a given key with only one map lookup?

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin

Say I have a map:

```
 var inventory = mutableMapOf("apples" to 1, "oranges" to 2)
```

and I want to increment the number of apples by one.

However this does not work:

```
inventory["apples"]!!++ // Error:(9, 4) Variable expected
```

This neither:

```
var apples = inventory["apples"]!!
++apples
println(inventory["apples"]) // prints "1" => the value was not incremented.
```

Which is surprising, since in Kotlin, numbers are [boxed when they are stored in instances of generic objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html). I would not expect that a copy is being made.

It seems that the only way is to do something like:

```
var apples = inventory["apples"]!!
++apples
inventory["apples"] = apples
println(inventory["apples"])
```

Which both uses two lookups in the map and is extremely ugly and lengthy.

Is there a way to increment a value of a given key using only one lookup?

Also, could someone explain why the first two methods do not work?

Comment: Never used `Kotlin`, but after looking at your code, I would try something like `inventory["apples"] = ++inventory["apples"]!!`

Comment: @Sedrick Thank you! However it does not work: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/2b24n4oloe1uteuhkruoesdjid/ef89kpeif5i7sd3ls27taa8gar

Kotlin is a language that uses the Java standard library. So anything that is possible in Java should be possible in Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to increment the value with only one `get` and without a `put`. You always need to do a `put` afterwards, because `Int` is immutable. The `inc()` method (`++` is a shortcut for that) returns a new value that need to be stored in the map. It does not change the stored value.

You can use

```
inventory.computeIfPresent("apples") { _, v -> v + 1 }
```

To write it in one line, but if you look into the implementation it will also do a `get()` then compute the new value and do a `put()` afterwards. So you can save a line of code you have to write, but you will not save CPU cycles on execution time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
inventory.computeIfPresent("apples") { _, v -> v + 1 }
```

The first two methods don't work because when you retrieve a value from the map you get a primitive type, in your case `Integer`, which is immutable. When you change the value of an Integer you're simply pointing your variable at a new instance of Integer, you're not updating that Integer instance which you were previously pointing at.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but the implementation does two lookups under the hood. Do you think it is possible to achieve with only one lookup?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik the computeIfPresent method does two lookups but if the map is created by `hashMapOf` then it only does one lookup. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Integers are boxed in maps, `Integer` is a primitive wrapper class, and [primitive wrapper classes are immutable in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primitive-wrapper-classes-are-immutable-in-java/), it seems that you'd like to mutate an immutable object, which is unfortunately not possible, at least not by any conventional or recommended means.

Take a look at [Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java), where there are several suggestions on how to improve the performance of integer value incrementing in maps, as well as one explicitly implementing your desired behavior through a wrapper class `MutableInt`, which also turns out to be the fastest (~20% faster than the baseline).

Answer (score 2):

The `computeIfPresent` method in java.util.HashMap only does **one lookup**. So you can use:

```
var inventory = hashMapOf("apples" to 1, "oranges" to 2)
inventory.computeIfPresent("apples") { _, v -> v + 1 }  // Only 1 lookup!
```

Note: this is an implementation detail. It does one lookup in the current version of Kotlin (1.3.11) using a specific implementation of Java (Oracle HotSpot 11.0.1). Other configurations may or may not use different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea

```
// Declaration
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
// Increment
map.put("x", map.getOrPut("x"){ 1 } + 1)
```