# Increase value in mutable map

Tags: kotlin

I created a `mutableMap<String, Int>` and created a record "Example" to `0`. How can I increase value, f.e. to `0 + 3` ?

Comment: Get value from map, increment it, set new value to map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment value of a given key with only one map lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781965/how-to-increment-value-of-a-given-key-with-only-one-map-lookup)

Answer (score 42):

You could use the [`getOrDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get-or-default.html)
function to get the old value or 0, add the new value and assign it back to the map.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
map["Example"] = map.getOrDefault("Example", 0) + 3
```

Or use the [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function from the standard `Map` interface.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
map.merge("Example", 3) {
    old, value -> old + value
}
```

Or more compact:

```
map.merge("Example",3, Int::plus)
```

Comment: ... just as a side-note: if you also want to remove some entries on certain conditions, [`Map.compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) may also be helpful... or generally have a look at the [`Map`-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) then

Comment: if you are on android, note that this requires API 24

Comment: Use 1 atomic method `merge` or `compute` to support concurrency

Answer (score 12):

How I do it:

```kotlin
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()

map[key] = (map[key] ?: 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define

```
fun <K> MutableMap<K, Int>.inc(key: K): Int = merge(key, 1, Math::addExact)!!
```

So you can so something like

```
map.inc("Example")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getOrDefault if API level is greater than 23. Otherwise you can use elvis operator

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
val value = map["Example"] ?: 0
map["Example"] = value + 3
```