# Increment element in mutable map in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, mutable, mutablemap

I am coming to Kotlin 1.3 from Scala. I am trying to do something very simple:

```
class Foo {
    fun bar() {
        val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
        val index = "foo"
        if (index !in map)
          map[index] = 0
        else
          map[index]!! += 1
    }
}
```

However, IntelliJ 2020 gives me an error on the `+=` operator, complaining that "Variable expected", which is opaque to me. Why can't I do this? I have tried lots of variations but none works. IntelliJ even offers to generate the identical code if I leave off the `!!` operator and select `Add non-null asserted (!!) call` from the context menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase value in mutable map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826903/increase-value-in-mutable-map)

Comment: It doesn't. It just gives some hacky workarounds without explaining why something so simple doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `operator fun get()` returns null if the key doesn't exist, you can use the null safety instead of the if check:

```kotlin
val toPut = map[index]?.plus(3) ?: 0
map[index] = toPut
```

The reason you cannot use `+` is because `operator fun Int.plus()` is only applicable to non-null `Int` types. Though this doesn't looks that bad.