# How to store duplicates from an arraylist with an amount

Tags: java, arraylist, frequency

I have a problem where I want to keep the original arraylist and want to make two separate arraylist where one doesn't contain any duplicates and the other the amount of items in the first arraylist. 
For example:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
ArrayList<Item> items2 = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
ArrayList<Item> occurences = new ArrayList<Item>();

items[0, 1, 2] would have bandana bandana bandana
items2[0] would have bandana
occurences[0] would have 3
```

Comment: How do you want to store Integer in ArrayList<Items> as occurences ? Isn't it better to hold variable or just take items.size() ? Is Item your class or it is just an example ?

Comment: Why not just create a ``Map<Item, Integer>`` where key is the item, and value is the frequency

Comment: If the `Item` is a `POJO` then what is a rule to determine their equality?

Answer (score 0):

Below code shows an example of what you need but instead of Item (I don't know if you put it as example or it's your class) there are String to store elements and Integer for occurences.

To store elements without duplicates I suggest to use Set

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> items2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<Integer> occurences = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    items.add("bandana");
    items.add("bandana");
    items.add("bandana");

    items2.addAll(new HashSet<>(items)); // create Hashset to remove duplicates and add again to Arraylist
    occurences.add(items.size()); // add size of items list as first element

    items.forEach(System.out::println);   // Print: "bandana" "bandana" "bandana"
    items2.forEach(System.out::println);  // Print: "bandana"
    occurences.forEach(System.out::println); // Print: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it but I would try something like this:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
ArrayList<Item> items2 = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
ArrayList<Item> occurences = new ArrayList<Item>();

for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
{
    Item x = items.get(i);
    int count=1;

    if(!items2.contains(x))
    {
        items2.add(x);
        for(int j=i+1; j<items.size(); j++)
        {
            if(items2.get(j)==x)
                count++;
        }
        ocurrences.add(count);
    }
}
```

You might want to change `Item` to `int` for the occurrences list.

Answer (score 0):

## No Duplicates in Collection

For the collection that should have no duplicate Items, use a `Set<Item>` instead of an `ArrayList<Item>`. The `Set` data structure **will not store duplicates**. Since `Item` is a custom object you created, you will need to override the `hashCode` and `equals` method in your `Item` class.

This approach is **O(1)** - which is way better than keep an `ArrayList<Item>` and iterating it and searching for a duplicate (which will be **O(n)** at worst).

## Occurrences

For the occurrences problem, instead of keeping your items in an `ArrayList<Item>`, keep them in a `Map<Item,Integer>`. This will map the item to how many occurrences there are of it.

Using the map, you will need to get the key, which is the `Item` you are about to add. If it already exists in the map, simply add one to the value of that key (the occurrences number).

If they key doesn't exist yet (this is the first time this `Item` will be inserted into the map), simply add it to the map, and set the value as 1.

Using a map will also be a way more efficient solution, as it will also be **O(1)**, instead of **O(n)** if an `ArrayList<Item>` will be used.

## Example:

```
Set<Item> itemSet = new HashSet<>();
Map<Item,Integer> occurencesMap = new HashMap<>();

        itemSet.add(yourItem);
        itemSet.add(yourItem);
        itemSet.add(secondItem);
        //itemSet now contains only 2 objects!


        if (occurencesMap.get(yourItem) == null){
            occurencesMap.put(yourItem,1);
        }
        else{
            //adding 1 to the current value of occurences for that item.
            occurencesMap.get(yourItem)++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Java 8 streams you could also do it this way:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("bandana", "helmet", "bandana",
                           "bandana", "silk hat", "basecap", "silk hat");

Map<String, Long> result = items.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result); //prints {silk hat=2, helmet=1, bandana=3, basecap=1}
```

Instead of two lists with the distinct values and the occurences you will have a map with the item itself as key (Function.identity()) and the number of occurences as the value (Collectors.counting()).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using streams and lambda functions. I moddified `occurence` to be a `Map<Item, Integer>` so that we can count per item

```
items.stream().forEach( i -> {
    if (!items2.contains(i)) {
        items2.add(i);
    }
    occurences.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
});
```

The very cool use of `merge` was found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648785/9223839). Since we don't know what `Item` i I tested this using `String` instead so `equals` etc worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Using lambdas to get a list of distinct values:

```
ArrayList items2 = items.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

If I understood correctly you need the number of occurrences for each item:

```
Map<Item, Integer> m = new HashMap();
items.stream().forEach(k-> m.merge(k,1, Integer::sum));
ArrayList occurrences = new ArrayList(m.values());
```

The order in `occurrences` does not reflect the order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate each list as below,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> items2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();

    items.addAll(Arrays.asList("bandana", "bandana", "bandana", "abc", "abc"));

    items2.addAll(new LinkedHashSet<>(items));

    for (String item : items2)
    {
      occurrences.add(Collections.frequency(items, item));
    }

    System.out.println(items);
    System.out.println(items2);
    System.out.println(occurrences);
  }
}
```