# How can I count how many men and women are in each province, and that these provinces are ordered by country in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays, object

As you can see, it's an *ArrayList* of objects and I need each of these objects to count their province attributes based on men and women

```
class Registro {
    String region;
    String province;
    String gender;
}

List<Registro> reg = new ArrayList<Registro>();
        reg.add(new Registro("China","Beigin","male"));
        reg.add(new Registro("China","Beigin","female"));
        reg.add(new Registro("China","x","male"));
        reg.add(new Registro("China","x","female"));
        reg.add(new Registro("China","x","male"));
        reg.add(new Registro("EEUU","SB","female"));
        reg.add(new Registro("EEUU","SB","female"));
        reg.add(new Registro("EEUU","CAL","male"));
        reg.add(new Registro("EEUU","CAL","male"));
```

The desired output

```
  /*

China, Beigin, 1 male, 1 female 
China,    x  , 2 male, 1 female 
EEUU,    SB  , 0 male, 2 female 
EEUU,    CAL , 2 male, 0 female */
```

Comment: You can try to write your own priorityqueue object. It will sort based on province name when offered a new "Registro", and you can override the offer method to call the parent offer, then also have a hashmap object where you add numbers to the province name to keep track of count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A `Map` for each sex

One quick and dirty approach would be a pair of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) objects, for male and female each, where the key is a combination of your country and region while the value is an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) for the count of elements found.

```
Map< String , Integer > females = new TreeMap<>() ;
Map< String , Integer > males = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Loop your collection of `Registro` objects. For each `Registro` object, get the country and region, and [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation). Use some arbitrary character as a [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter), such as a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) `|` (VERTICAL LINE), so you can later [pull country and region apart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/642706) (if need be). That string is the key in your map.

The value in the map, the `Integer` object, is a count of `Registro` objects for that country-region in that sex. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648785/642706) to learn about using [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) to increment the map’s `Integer` value using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), `Integer::sum`.

```
String key = registro.getCountry() + "|" + registro.getRegion() ;
if( registro.getSex().equals( "female" ) )
{
    females.merge( key , 1 , Integer::sum ) ;
} 
else if( registro.getSex().equals( "male" ) )
{
    males.merge( key , 1 , Integer::sum ) ;
} 
else // defensive programming
{ 
    … handle error condition, illegal state.
}
```

To build your report, get a distinct set of all keys from both maps. Use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) for this, as a set eliminates duplicates. The `Set` returned by [`Map::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) is actually a view onto the map rather than a separate collection. So we pass that set for one sex to constructor of a new and separate set. For the other sex, we call [`Set::addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)). Thus we combine the two maps’ keys into a single distinct set.

We use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) to keep the keys in natural order, matching the [natural order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) used by the [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
Set< String > keys = new TreeSet<>( females.keySet() ) ;  // Build a fresh independent set from the set returned by `Map::keySet`. 
keys.addAll( males.keySet() ) ;                           // Add in all the keys from the other map, automatically eliminating duplicates.
```

To build your report, loop the `keys` set. For each key, call `females.getKey` to get back a count, and call `males.getKey` to get back a count. If either returns a null, report zero for that sex in that country-region.

```
for( String key : keys ){
    Integer countFemales = Objects.requireNonNullElse​( females.getKey( key ) , new Integer( 0 ) ) ;
    Integer countMales = Objects.requireNonNullElse​( males.getKey( key ) , new Integer( 0 ) ) ;

    String output = key + " = " + countFemales + " females, " + countMales + " males." ;
}
```

> China|Beigin = 13 females, 7 males.

The approach described here assumes your collection of `Registro` objects is not being modified by another thread.

I expect there are other ways to solve your problem, likely more elegant no doubt. But this should get the job. I would use this approach myself.

By the way, here is a graphic table I made showing the attributes of various `Map` implementations.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]