# How can I sort the letters of a word according to the order of occurrences compatible with Java 7?

Tags: java, string, sorting, oop

I need to print all the letters that appear in the word, rearranged so that the letters that appear most frequently are found at the beginning.

The word can contain up to 100,000 characters.

If there are letters that appear the same number of times, the smallest ones will be displayed first after alphabetical sorting.

Some classes and operations are slow in Java. For this reason, it is recommended to use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter.

Concatenation using String is slow.

Input: instructions

Output : iinnssttcour

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 String line;
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(System.in));
 line = reader.readLine();

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<>();

     int len = line.length();

      for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           char ch = line.charAt(i);
           charCountMap.put(ch, charCountMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
      }

      charCountMap.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(Map.Entry.<Character, 
     Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                 .forEach(record -> {
                    Character key = record.getKey();
                    int value = record.getValue();

                    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                          sb.append(key);
                     }
        });

        sb.toString();
        System.out.println(sb);
     }
  }
```

My second solution is working too slow.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String inputString;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
inputString = reader.readLine();
if(reader != null)
 reader.close();
    int[] letterArray = new int[26];
    char[] letters = new char[26];
    for(int i=0;i<=25;i++)
        letters[i] = (char)(97+i);
    for(int i=0; i< inputString.length(); i++)
        letterArray[inputString.charAt(i) - 97] +=1 ;
    for(int i=0; i<=24;i++)
        for(int j=i+1;j<=25;j++){
            if(letterArray[i] <letterArray[j] || (letterArray[i] == 
               letterArray[j] && letters[i] > letters[j])){
                int temp = letterArray[i];
                letterArray[i] = letterArray[j];
                letterArray[j] = temp;
                char temp2;
                temp2 = letters[i];
                letters[i] = letters[j];
                letters[j] = temp2;}
        }
      String outputString = new String();
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<letterArray[i]; j++)
                outputString += letters[i];}
     System.out.println(outputString);}
     }
```

Comment: Hi, please tell us what you have tried so far to solve this assignment :)

Comment: Hello , I was thinking of  using a frequency vector but is not needed for this solution so right now I dont't have an idea .

Comment: SO is not meant to do other people's homework ;) I'd recommend iterating over all characters using a BufferedReader and incrementing a value in a map (character => amount). This map could be your frequency vector. There is an interesting answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/107987/7381844 about incrementing a value in a map ;)
After that you have a map like a => 100, b => 10, ... that you have to sort first by the value and then by the key. After that iterate the number of occurrences for each character to append the character to a BufferedWriter or a StringBuilder.

Comment: Try to get as far as possible. Then if you have a problem post it here so we can help you :)

Comment: I've updated the post with something I tried but it seems that it is not in an alphabetical order. The out put is : "ssttiinnrcuo" for instructions. What can I modify?

Comment: The `sorted` method takes a `Comparator` to determine the correct order. The inbuilt `comparingByValue()` only honours the value. That is why in your result all 2-times-characters come before all only-once-characters, but they are not sorted by character.
To fix this you need to write your own comparator (which might sound a little intimidating but is actually quite simple). I'll post an answer for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there :)
As mentioned in the comments you need to write your own comparator to sort the entries of your map according to count and character.

```
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line;
    line = "instructions"; // I've left out the Reader for brevity's sake

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<>();

    int len = line.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char ch = line.charAt(i);
        charCountMap.put(ch, charCountMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
    }

    charCountMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((first, second) -> {
        if (first.getValue() > second.getValue())
            return -1;
        if (first.getValue().equals(second.getValue()))
            return first.getKey() - second.getKey();
        return 1;
    }).forEach(record -> {
                Character key = record.getKey();
                int value = record.getValue();

                for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                    sb.append(key);
                }
            });

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The comparator (here declared as a functional interface) first checks the count of the letters. Only if they are equal it also checks for the character in place.

### Update: JAVA 7

Java 7 cannot handle Streams/Lambdas/... therefore we have to be a litte more verbose but we can still achieve the same thing.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputString;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputString = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<>();

        int len = inputString.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char ch = inputString.charAt(i);
            // getOrDefault is not available for Java 7
            Integer currentValue = charCountMap.get(ch);
            if (currentValue == null)
                currentValue = 0;
            charCountMap.put(ch, currentValue + 1);
        }

        // Conversion of Map to List is somewhat more complicated
        List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> charCountList = new ArrayList<>(charCountMap.entrySet());

        // Functional Interfaces / Lambdas do not yet exist so we need to declare the comparator explicitly
        Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> first, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> second) {
                if (first.getValue() > second.getValue())
                    return -1;
                if (first.getValue().equals(second.getValue()))
                    return first.getKey() - second.getKey();
                return 1;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(charCountList, comparator);

        // StringBuilder does already exist
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : charCountList) {
            Character key = entry.getKey();
            int value = entry.getValue();

            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                sb.append(key);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

I've commented on the differences between the Java 7 / 8 versions, but it still looks quite similar, doesn't it?

Your code example works as well, but you are kinda reinventing the wheel with all that heavy array-working. In other words: It works - but it ain't pretty ;)

Comment: I'm getting 15 errors and javac failed: errno= return=256 at /usr/local/bin/gruntmaster-compile line 23.
I think I need to use an older version of Java ,maybe 7 . My code works , but what can I modify to solve that problem?

Comment: So your code works regularly but when you try to compile it with grunt it throws an error?

Comment: No, the code works great, but the platform where I need to upload my solution uses an older version of Java I think (maybe Java 7) so that's why I'm getting that error...

Comment: What should I modify?

Comment: Java 7 does not support streams.

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this problem to work with Java 7.

Comment: I've tried something else without streams but I'm getting an output limit exceeded. I've updated the post with my solution. How can I make it faster?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a Java 7 compliant solution of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Need to sort your Map by value reversed, then by key.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the map is only sorted by frequency of letters `Map.Entry.<Character, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()` After that, it should have been sorted in alphabetical order.

You can use `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` to achieve the 'after' part of sorting.

`valueComparator` to sort by frequency of letters:

```
Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>> valueComparator = (e1, e2) -> 
                e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());  // reverse order
```

then `keyComparator` to sort in alphabetical order:

```
Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>> keyComparator = valueComparator
                .thenComparing((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey()));
```

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap  = new HashMap<>();

for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
}

Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>> valueComparator = (e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>> keyComparator = valueComparator
        .thenComparing((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey()));

charCountMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(keyComparator).forEach(e -> {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < e.getValue()) {
        sb.append(e.getKey());
        i++;
    }
});

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output:

```
iinnssttcoru
```

Comment: How can I make it without streams and also how can I use Bufferedwritten?